# Valores nulos no Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Então galera estou com um problema na hora de inserir um dado nas minhas tabelas do Oracle, insiro os dados através de uma rotina PLSQL, e gostaria de saber como insiro dados em uma respectiva tabela, porém caso um dos campos esteja vazio, quero que o valor NULL não seja inserido, segue minha rotina abaixo:

```
DECLARE
   ID_OCORRENCIA NUMBER;
BEGIN

INSERT INTO OCORRENCIA (CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA, DATA_UTC, UF, MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, NUMERO_FICHA, HISTORICO, HORA_UTC)
VALUES (:P2_CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA, :P2_DATA_UTC, :P2_UF, :P2_MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA, :P2_LATITUDE, :P2_LONGITUDE, :P2_NUMERO_FICHA, :P2_HISTORICO, :P2_HORA_UTC)
RETURNING ID INTO ID_OCORRENCIA;

INSERT INTO TIPO_OCORRENCIA (ID_OCORRENCIA, TIPO) VALUES (ID_OCORRENCIA, :P2_TIPO_OCORRENCIA);
INSERT INTO TIPO_OCORRENCIA (ID_OCORRENCIA, TIPO) VALUES (ID_OCORRENCIA, :P2_TIPO_OCORRENCIA_1);

END
```

O que acontece aqui é que ao inserir um tipo de ocorrência na tabela TIPO_OCORRENCIA, ele sempre inseri na tabela o valor que eu informo e também o valor NULL. Existe uma forma pra que isso não ocorra, e casa eu queria inserir apenas um dado, tenha apenas um dado na minha tabela e não dois.

Comment: Ao se referir a ID_OCORRENCIA como você diferencia se está se referindo ao campo da tabela ou à variável local de sua rotina?

Comment: Eu acho que você está fazendo confusão. Ele não está inserindo o valor NULL. Ele, de fato, não está inserindo valor algum, quando você ver NULL é porque não foi inserido nada. Para evitar que aquele campo fique nulo, você tem duas opções: trata isso no código ou crie o campo na tabela com a clausula NOT NULL.

Comment: Verdade o que vc disse, não está nulo o campo pois eu insiro o valor da chave estrangeira na tabela. Porém eu queria saber justamente como não inserir esse registro na tabela, caso ele esteja somente com a chave estrangeira preenchida, registro esse o TIPO no caso.

Comment: Problema já resolvido, utilizei um comando condicional "IF :P2_TIPO_OCORRENCIA_1 IS NOT NULL THEN INSERT INTO ...." e problema resolvido, mas valeu pelas dicas galera.